# jquery html append outputs excessive quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a quite peculiar problem with some jQuery code.
Basically I'm trying to work out a video mirror script where you click on a button and the div should change embed code to another video service. This is my code:

```
jQuery(function($){

    $('#mirror1').click(function(){
           $('#player-embed').html($('<div />').append($('#video1').clone()).html());
    });
});
```

This is the code for the button

```
function mirror1( $atts, $content = null ) {
return '<a class="wpb_button_a" title="Mirror 1" href="#mirror1" id="mirror1">
<spanclass="wpb_button  wpb_btn-primary wpb_regularsize">Mirror 1</span></a>
<div id="video1" class="video1">' . $content . '</div>';
```

My problem is that the output gives excessive " quotations
So all I'm seeing is (on page, not in code)

```
<iframe frameborder=”0″ width=”480″ height=”270″ src=”videourltest” allowfullscreen>    </iframe>
```

And not the actual video itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `spanclass="...` should be `span class="...` i presume?

Comment: also, javascript doesn't use `.` to concatenate strings, use `+`. And in JS you might want to use variable names without "$", it's very confusing and probably confused you into using the php style concatenation technique

Comment: as for your problem, I don't understand where the iframe comes from at all, I don't see that anywhere in your code. Am I missing something (which is very well possible, if I may add:)

Comment: the iframe comes from the $content variable in the PHP

Comment: que? PHP? that makes it very difficult (for me at least) to get a complete picture of the situation here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
<iframe frameborder=”0″ width=”480″ height=”270″ src=”videourltest” allowfullscreen>    </iframe>
```

Your `”` and `″` are typographic quotes and not code quotes, code quotes are straight like `"`

Try:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270" src="videourltest" allowfullscreen>    </iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It really was that simple...~